# Doing something after a file has been downloaded

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm kinda new to programming in general. My problem is that I want to download a file and after that do something.

```
Danbooru.search(tag, function (err, data) { //search for a random image with the given tag
    data.random() //selects a random image with the given tag
        .getLarge()  //get's a link to the image
        .pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream('random.jpg')); //downloads the image
    });
```

now I want to do a console.log after the file has been downloaded. I don't want to work with setTimeout since the files will take a diffrent time to download.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you. Just saving the request to a variable and checking for the `finish` event on it.

```
Danbooru.search(tag, function (err, data) { 
        var stream = data.random() 
            .getLarge() 
            .pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream('random.jpg'));

            stream.on('finish', function() { console.log('file downloaded'); });
        });
```